# Who Wants to Win a LaTeX Book in 2016?

Tags: discussion

I am organising a lottery and Springer have kindly agreed to donate two copies of [LaTeX and Friends](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783642238154).

The lottery closes when the judge (I) announces the winners. The judge's decision is final and there shall be no discussion and or correspondence about the outcome of the lottery.

To win the book you must guess a number in the range 1--200 and post it as an answer to this question. The first person who guesses the right number wins the book. Please note that the time of arrival in TeX-SX is what counts, not the time of sending.

To give everybody a fair chance, you may post only two numbers.

There is one exception to the previous rule. If several contestants guess the same number, the contestant whose guess arrived first is valid. The other contestants may post a new number.

Contestants must have been a member of TeX-SX before 1 December, 2016. (Without this restriction, people may start creating fake accounts and submit multiple guesses.)

Please post your guesses as an answer to this meta question; not as a comment. Comments will be ignored. Please only put your guess in the body of the answer.

Guesses will be checked every couple of days and the winner will be announced within a few days after.

The winners must send me a delivery address for the book to my personal email address. I shall keep these addresses private. If a winner wants to have their book signed, I can do so at their request.

The following numbers have been taken (numbers marked with `●●●` are already chosen):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|020|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|034|035|●●●|●●●|●●●|039|040|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|046|●●●|●●●|049|050|●●●|●●●|●●●|054|●●●|056|●●●|058|059|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|062|●●●|●●●|065|●●●|●●●|068|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|074|075|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|080|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|082|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|092|●●●|●●●|●●●|096|●●●|●●●|●●●|100|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|102|103|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|114|●●●|●●●|●●●|118|●●●|120|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|122|●●●|124|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|138|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|145|●●●|●●●|148|●●●|150|●●●|●●●|153|●●●|●●●|●●●|157|158|159|160|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|161|●●●|163|164|●●●|●●●|167|●●●|●●●|170|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|176|●●●|178|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|182|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|190|●●●|●●●|193|●●●|195|196|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT: This is not getting anywhere.** All guesses are wrong so far:( From 18 December, 21:14 GMT on, everybody is allowed to submit up to two guesses.

**EDIT: 48 was one of the winning numbers. Congratulations to Torbjørn. One more number to go.**

**EDIT: We're almost there.** Only one guess has been right so far:( From 22 December, 11:49 GMT, 2016 on, each (valid) contestant (see above for rules) is allowed to submit up to three guesses.

**EDIT: 124 was the second winning number. Congratulations to Ryan. End of lottery.**

Comment: Thanks for moving this to Meta to @JosephWright. I should have put it there in the first place.

Comment: »Comments will be ignored.« ;(

Comment: Thanks to @paulocereda. Didn't understand the system. Makes much more sense this way as you don't have guess when crossing out a number.

Comment: Do I have to punch out the number myself? - Ah, I even cannot click Edit.

Comment: @mhchem If you can't do it, somebody will do it for you. It depends how much reputation you have ;).

Comment: How is it possible, that this question has 80 answers, but only 25 upvotes???

Comment: @samcarter They were too busy in finding a random number to remember to upvote the question :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Ah, that's a comforting explanation!

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Many thanks to you and to Springer for the chance! :)

Comment: Congratulations to the winners!  Thank you Springer for sponsoring.  Thanks everyone for your great work!

Comment: @cwx Thanks and thanks to everybody for participating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because people won :)

Comment: @percusse I second that motion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The winning numbers were 48 and 124. They were generated by the following `Java` program.

```
  import java.util.Random;

  public class Lottery2016 {
      public static void main( String[] args ) {
          final long SEED = 123456;
          final Random rand = new Random( SEED );

          final int fst = 1 + rand.nextInt( 200 );
          final int snd = 1 + rand.nextInt( 200 );

          System.out.println( "First winninng number is:  " + fst );
          System.out.println( "Second winninng number is: " + snd );
      }
  }
```

Of course I apologise for not having generated the numbers  with LaTeX or TeX.

Comment: The reason of closing your question makes smile on my face:     "This question does not appear to be about TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question." :-)

Answer (score 15):

117

```
import numpy as np
print(np.random.randint(1,200))
```

Second guess:

48

Comment: Damn, didn't read the docs properly, that should have been `(1,201)`. But whatever.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Comment: Thanks to @PauloCereda for acting as the punch squad. Without the punching I would not have noticed this _winning_ number. Congratulations. Please send me your snail mail details and I'll post a copy of the book as soon as I have it. Do you want to have it signed?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I won? Awesome! Will send an email to your UCC email address with snail mail details. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

9

> because it's the smallest prime number

**Edit**:

Second guess -> 27

> For random reasons :)

Comment: I don't think 9 is a prime number, :)

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Comment: Also 27 punched!

Comment: Does this mean I have to choose another?

Comment: No, 27 is correct, I've punched it in the punch card, in this way other people can see that it's been already chosen (by you)!

Comment: Thank you. You see, its not easy locating prime numbers these days...

Comment: I'm wondering what is your definition of _prime_ numbers... :)

Comment: It easy!! 

Every number is a prime number *unless*, its divisor is found...

Comment: Then, while you call 9 and 27 _prime_? They are both power of 3!

Answer (score 6):

Yay, a book! `:)`

I will go with **200** because I have no idea why! Also, ducks are very good at picking random numbers! `:)`

Thanks for the contest, Marc!

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched! Also, ducks should not enter such contests, as they tend to win all the time!

Answer (score 6):

Thank you very much for organizing this lottery. Here is my guess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\begin{document}
    The random number I choose is
    \pgfmathparse{int(rnd*199+1)}\pgfmathresult.
\end{document}
```

> The random number I choose is 192.

Edit: As a second guess is allowed from now on, I had to recompile a couple of times until I got a second valid guess:

> The random number I choose is 155.

Answer (score 4):

i'll spring for this.  my guess is 113.  thanks for the opportunity.

since you've opened it up to two guesses, i'll add a second -- 76.

third try: 031.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 4):

```
010
```

Would you like to make me happy? Give me a book!

Second chance:

```
110
```

Third choice:

```
030
```

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 4):

12!

(Today is 12th of the 12th. Question was posted "12 hours ago", as I type......)

Thanks!

Comment: One minute later and it would have been 12 o'clock in some timezone.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 4):

I originally went for ●●●, but as that has gone I decided to go for 86 instead.

(*Note to the punch-card squad: you're too slow, I got there first.*)

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* oh no! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for doing this lottery!

My guess is 42, but I need a more characters to submit this answer ....

My second guess is 142.

And my third guess is 129.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Comment: Second numbered punched as well.

Comment: 3rd number punched.

Answer (score 3):

175

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_No.*5*(Mozart)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_No._5_(Mozart))

Second choice:

15

Opus number of Beethoven's first piano concerto now playing

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

It's a great book! My guess is 22.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

Let's guess 23, free lunch! (if a book were lunch)

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

184 for me please

```
sample(1:200,1)
[1] 184
```

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

Here was my algorithm for choosing a number: I looked for a book in my office that had a bookmark in it. First I picked up Dretske's *Knowledge and the Flow of Information* but the bookmark was at p.214. Damn. Then I found Stalnaker's *Inquiry* with its bookmark at p.90. So:

```
90
```

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

135 
Just an odd number chosen at random (also the combo for my bike lock in the previous millennium!)

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

I am really interested and hope I win this time ;)

My lucky number would be 21 and I hope that not the bank wins...

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

53 is my guess.

Thanks for the opportunity, Marc!

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

144, because [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

I'll guess 78 because encrypted.google.com

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Comment: Also, this bloke is playing croquet on a dinosaur! `:)`

Comment: @paulo Ya lol, I use a browser that still has that as default. I have to change it...

Answer (score 3):

OK. I don't understand how punch cards work in this question as opposed to the duck one and am very confused.

Anyway, I guess

13

I have my reasons.

Comment: I also don't understand punch cards. I just copied and pasted the text from the reference suggested by @percusse. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen and @cfr: don't worry, friends! I fixed the table, hopefully. `:)`

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Comment: @cfr: ducks are very good with punched card technology and table organization! Also, ducks are highly prolific at picking random numbers! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Hwyaden to the rescue! Thank you! I really messed the punch card up .... I did undo my mess, though.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Well everybody else understood OK. I just expected it to work the way it has worked in other cases i.e. when you take a number, it is punched out and replaced by holes. But then it seemed every number remaining was already taken. So I assumed none were left .... So I guessed *i* so I could imagine entering. But then I realised there weren't enough answers for all the numbers to be gone.

Answer (score 3):

I'll submit 173 as my answer.  Just getting to thirty characters.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

14, one plus the previous answer.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

77 and 179 (since we are now allowed two guesses).

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Comment: @PauloCereda: Added new guess. What do I need to do to puch the number (so I can save you some work next time)?

Comment: To punch the number you simply have to edit the question but I've already done it for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I'll guess one (1), because you gotta start somewhere.

Comment: *The punched card squad says:* number punched!

Answer (score 3):

33 please. Good luck everyone.

**Second guess:** 180.

Answer (score 2):

I choose 105: my present reputation modulo 200.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=random+number+between+0+and+200

```
Result:
45
```

Edit: And the second guess from wolfram:

```
Result:
88
```

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 2):

My choice is 174 because it's my sons height

Answer (score 2):

191

The largest Sofie Germain prime less than 201.

Comment: Unfortunately, 191 was already taken: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/7049/101651, choose another number!

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess **165** which is not a random number to me although it has nothing to do whatsoever with TeX or the contest.

Thanks for the lottery.

EDIT: Second guess is **151**, also for obvious non-reasons.

Comment: *Numbers punched*

Comment: *Second numbers punched*

Answer (score 1):

I will go with `006` . . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

My guess is 073. My guess is 073.

Answer (score 1):

111, because 110 is police and 112 is fire department!

Answer (score 1):

037

Answer (score 1):

28 It is the largest perfect number in the list.

Answer (score 1):

139 and some more characters to reach thirty.

Answer (score 1):

026.....................................

Answer (score 1):

I choose 156 because meh ......

82 and 158 are my two new numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to have 112, in germany, thats the number of the fire brigade.  It is also the first checkbox of Zapf Dingbats, if I recall correct!

Bye and merry christmas

Jan

Answer (score 1):

166, because it is nice to say "one hundred and sssixty sssix"

Answer (score 1):

47. Let's see if I get lucky :)

Answer (score 1):

`CL-USER> (+ (random 200) 1)
8`

Answer (score 1):

101

.....................................

Answer (score 1):

147, feels like it must be correct

Answer (score 1):

A book! Nice! (Although I have it at the university's library, it would be nice a personal copy).

I choose **198** because it's the highest prime minus one (and 199 was taken) Why a prime? Because it's the fist thing that occurred to me...

Comment: (number punched!)

Comment: 199 was already taken by Vishal Gupta (see previous messages), I think the the punched card squad is a bit late...

Comment: Oops. Re-punched 198!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this offer. My number is: 25

Answer (score 1):

104 for me, please. Hopefully I'll be lucky!

Answer (score 1):

69. Because if 6 turned out to be 9 then 69 would not be possible.

Comment: Sorry, 69 has already been taken earlier than you.

Answer (score 1):

177 024 ‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏064

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX versions are representations of Pi with increasing precision.

```
import math
math.round(3.1415926535897)
```

> 3

Number 3, I choose you!! (But if 3 is taken, I'll take the closest unpunched value to 3.14159)

Edit by CarLaTeX: I've punched `004` for you.

Answer (score 1):

**72**

Thank you for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

**6**, the smallest Perfect Number in the lot! :)

Comment: 6 was already taken: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/7063/101651, choose another number!

Answer (score 1):

I choose 
31
because is my birthday.

Comment: 1 was already taken: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/7030/101651, choose another number :)

Answer (score 1):

168, hope no one else has chosen this one.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is 128, not random but seemed right.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a nice present I'm not sure I could convince my wife to offer me `(-;`. Thank you for the lottery!

I'd entrust my luck to **`017`**! (Card punched)

***Edit:*** My second choice is **`130`** for no rational reason, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

**LyX ERT**:
`The random number I choose is \pgfmathparse{int(rnd*199+1)}\pgfmathresult.`

**Premable**:
`\usepackage{pgfmath}`

**Result**:
The random number I choose is 149.

(Following [hbaderts](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7046/23423).)

Comment: Number punched!

Comment: Then I'll take 183

Comment: (that's taken).  I'll instead take 186 and 190.

Comment: I've punched 183 and 186.  
183 is free because the person who chose it can't vote since he is a new user: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/7134/101651, is it OK?

Comment: However, edit your answer to make it appear as active

Comment: It doesn't matter, the lottery is ended :)

Comment: Thanks :-) Glad to have participated anyway!

Answer (score 1):

93

But you should probably send the book to https://random.org if I win.

Answer (score 1):

My numbers are
**`38`** and **`119`**.
I hope I win this time.

Comment: Numbers punched!

Comment: @ebo: Can I write new numbers?

Answer (score 1):

First guess not already chosen: 36

Second guess: 94

Implementation:

```
tglase@tglase:~ $ cat x
# arc4random(3) in Pure mksh™
set -A seedbuf -- $(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=257 count=1 2>&- | \
    hexdump -ve '1/1 "0x%02X "')
set -A rs_S
typeset -i rs_S rs_i=-1 rs_j=0 n
while (( ++rs_i < 256 )); do
    (( rs_S[rs_i] = rs_i ))
done
rs_i=-1
while (( ++rs_i < 256 )); do
    (( n = rs_S[rs_i] ))
    (( rs_j = (rs_j + n + seedbuf[rs_i]) & 0xFF ))
    (( rs_S[rs_i] = rs_S[rs_j] ))
    (( rs_S[rs_j] = n ))
done
rs_i=0
rs_j=0
typeset -i rs_out
function arcfour_byte {
    typeset -i si sj

    (( rs_i = (rs_i + 1) & 0xFF ))
    (( si = rs_S[rs_i] ))
    (( rs_j = (rs_j + si) & 0xFF ))
    (( sj = rs_S[rs_j] ))
    (( rs_S[rs_i] = sj ))
    (( rs_S[rs_j] = si ))
    (( rs_out = rs_S[(si + sj) & 0xFF] ))
}
(( n = 256 * 12 + seedbuf[256] + (RANDOM & 0xFF) ))
while (( n-- )); do
    arcfour_byte
done
(( n = rs_out ))
while (( n-- )); do
    arcfour_byte
done

typeset -Uui16 -Z11 arc4random_rv
function arc4random {
    # apply uncertainty
    arcfour_byte
    (( rs_out & 1 )) && arcfour_byte
    # read four octets into result dword
    arcfour_byte
    (( arc4random_rv = rs_out ))
    arcfour_byte
    (( arc4random_rv |= rs_out << 8 ))
    arcfour_byte
    (( arc4random_rv |= rs_out << 16 ))
    arcfour_byte
    (( arc4random_rv |= rs_out << 24 ))
}

# arc4random_uniform(3) in Pure mksh™
function arc4random_uniform {
    # Derived from code written by Damien Miller <djm@openbsd.org>
    # published under the ISC licence, with simplifications by
    # Jinmei Tatuya. Written in mksh by Thorsten Glaser.
    #-
    # Calculate a uniformly distributed random number less than
    # upper_bound avoiding “modulo bias”.
    # Uniformity is achieved by generating new random numbers
    # until the one returned is outside the range
    # [0, 2^32 % upper_bound[. This guarantees the selected
    # random number will be inside the range
    # [2^32 % upper_bound, 2^32[ which maps back to
    # [0, upper_bound[ after reduction modulo upper_bound.
    #-
    typeset -Ui upper_bound=$1 min

    if (( upper_bound < 2 )); then
        arc4random_rv=0
        return
    fi

    # calculate (2^32 % upper_bound) avoiding 64-bit math
    # if upper_bound > 2^31: 2^32 - upper_bound (only one
    # “value area”); otherwise (x <= 2^31) use the fact
    # that ((2^32 - x) % x) == (2^32 % x)
    ((# min = upper_bound > 0x80000000 ? 1 + ~upper_bound :
        (0xFFFFFFFF - upper_bound + 1) % upper_bound ))

    # This could theoretically loop forever but each retry has
    # p > 0.5 (worst case, usually far better) of selecting a
    # number inside the range we need, so it should rarely need
    # to re-roll (at all).
    while :; do
        arc4random
        ((# arc4random_rv >= min )) && break
    done

    ((# arc4random_rv %= upper_bound ))
}
tglase@tglase:~ $ arc4random_uniform 200
tglase@tglase:~ $ print $((1+arc4random_rv))
23
tglase@tglase:~ $ . ./x
tglase@tglase:~ $ arc4random_uniform 200
tglase@tglase:~ $ print $((1+arc4random_rv))
36
tglase@tglase:~ $ arc4random_uniform 200
tglase@tglase:~ $ print $((1+arc4random_rv))
94
```

Yes, I like my Korn Shell ;-)

Comment: I marked them as taken in list of numbers in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Onehundredandthirtyone (131)..

Comment: *The punched card squad says: number punched!*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 97? I'm sure it is not...

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with the current lower extreme: **002**

Comment: numbers punched

Comment: Yes!!!! Not seen that I'll Keep only the 002. Thanks for the warning (I'm embarassed). `xD`

Answer (score 0):

108 .......... .......... .......

Answer (score 0):

152                           .

Answer (score 0):

85 Eighty-five. ...............

Answer (score 0):

121 (because it is 11^2, and a palindrom)

Answer (score 0):

I will go with 199 because its the largest prime (less than 200) which can be expressed as sum of squares.

Answer (score 0):

106, cause it's a number and < 200

Answer (score 0):

Eleven (11) for reasons that are obvious in my head. :-)

Thanks for the lottery

Answer (score 0):

137 is my guess. For some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with 171! But that sentence is not long enough. May now...

Answer (score 0):

I will guess 191.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

63, because of Graham's number.

Answer (score 0):

3! My number, if I can reach the 30 characters, is the three.

Answer (score 0):

107 (one hundred seven) .......

Answer (score 0):

013­­­­­­­
...............
...............
...............
...............
...............

Comment: Hi Leonid, it looks like somebody has already taken that number [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/7025/65692).

Answer (score 0):

I am sure to contribute something new (hopefully, haha): I take the number 069! Would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

126. (adding characters here to reach the minimum!)

Answer (score 0):

188, for no particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

169, because it's 100 more than the maturest number.

Answer (score 0):

123 - obviously the right choice ;)

Answer (score 0):

99 because if 6 turned out to be 9, then 69 (already taken) would be 99. Which I hope has not been taken.

Comment: It was not taken. Card punched (just to see if I've got enough reputation to do it: yes, I've got)!

Answer (score 0):

I take 127, because I just like it!

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

115, because of

```
expr 1 + $(tr -cd '0-9' < /dev/urandom|fold -w 3|grep -E '^[01]'|head -1)
```

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

007

James Bond asks you to donate the book to refugees from the war in Aleppo (I blame Putin for the ongoing fatalities there). Or simply to a library in need of support, maybe a university library in a struggling country.

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with 162, because it looks so nice.

Answer (score 0):

Can I take 095? It's nineteen times five.

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

057

because it is equally good to any other number

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

81. (081). Because I want to win!!!!!

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

Well … really, no Lua?

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\Huge\directlua{tex.sprint(math.random(200))}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Using this I chose **067**.  That must be exactly right, it was computed with a computer.

[image]
… and I chose an additional number as granted.  It’s the **197**, and this must be correct, too, because it was computed with a computer, too.

Punched it out myself, this time.  Sorry if this wasn’t correct.

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

146

this is my second guess

Comment: Number punched!

Answer (score 0):

125, 187
answer must be at least 30 characters

Comment: Numbers punched!

Answer (score 0):

Let's just pick **43** and **143** semi-randomly.

Comment: Numbers punched

Answer (score 0):

184. Just because I saw this number wasn't taken by anyone.

Comment: 184 was already taken: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/7017/101651, choose another number!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for this cool betting game. I already feel lucky that I just stumbled across it.

But let's guess some numbers to see if I can reach even more.

**71** and **172**

A nice Christmas time to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

I choose the numbers 44 and 133.

Comment: New numbers punched!

Answer (score 0):

Let it be 005 (my second choice).

Comment: Number punched.

Answer (score 0):

154 for the first guess

194 for the second one

Comment: Numbers punched.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I punched the numbers for you, they were not already taken. So I'll remove your two new guesses from this answer.

Comment: Ok. My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, I see that my first comment could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

79 and 52, in that order. No fewer, no less.

Comment: Numbers punched.

Answer (score 0):

I choose 16 and 98 in that order.

Comment: Numbers punched.

Answer (score 0):

083 and 084 because ... nothing.

Comment: I marked them as taken in list of numbers in the question.

Answer (score 0):

My numbers are
030 and 100 
I hope I will win............ :)

Comment: I'm afraid that, being a member for only a week, you're not actually eligible to enter. See the rules in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go for **87** and **132** - because of reasons...

Comment: I marked them as taken in list of numbers in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love 55 because it is nicely framed by 054 and 056.

Comment: I marked it as taken in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with

```
66
```

and `140`

Comment: I have punched it

Answer (score 0):

89 and 116

And I am wondering how the book might be sent? in pdf?

Comment: It's a physical copy, of paper, so regular old snail mail. Edit: I edited the first post, so your numbers are marked as taken.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I choose the numbers 19 and 91

Answer (score 0):

Let my second answer be 51.  No particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

Boy, for some reason 60 is also calling my name.

Answer (score 0):

61  because it is the smallest Centered hexagonal number left

Answer (score 0):

I will have 018. 
But surely we all have zero probability of success, unless the answer is an integer? Hope springs eternal...
Second guess: 041, for the rare case when 42 doesn't quite work.

Comment: I marked those as taken in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

My third and last guess is 136

Answer (score 0):

I choose the number 29 and 134.

Answer (score 0):

Chosen by purely mental processes:

32

109

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot with following numbers: 70 and 189.

Answer (score 0):

My third choice is 170 ....................

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess 158!

Second Guess 124.

Comment: Good man yourself. That's the second winning number. Please send me your snail-mail details and I will send a copy of the book as soon as I have it. Do you want the book signed?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen No kidding? My bad day just turned around! Signed for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Only now I saw this topic. Hopefully I could vote.

I choose
102
103
068

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the first non-taken number, so ... 034

Answer (score 0):

And for my second guess ... 193
:-)

Answer (score -1):

185 ..................................................

Comment: Note that you can select two numbers (I marked t185 as taken in the first post.)